# do we receive the com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER when user open the app through google play store?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

Do we receive the `com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER` broadcast when a user open the app through google play store (not install it, just open it)? I would like to measure reengagement: User with the app installed who follows on a campaign.